# Avoid/Detect manipulation of an exported file

Tags: c++, qt, security, hash

I am working on a C++ Qt application. To assist the user in case of a failure of the application or the device it is connected to, the program exports all the internal settings and stores them in a ordinary file (csv at the moment). This file is then sent to the company (eg. per mail).

To avoid unnoticed manipulations of the exported settings (eg. from the user by hand after the export), I need some kind of mechanismus to detect this.

The method sould be as simple as possible, since this is not a very critical information, but still effective.

All I can think of would be a hash or encryption, but I am pretty sure there is already a simple and elegant solution available for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of a variety kinds of digests or cryptographic signature schemes. Since this must work off-line, your executable must contain a secret - be it a public key used for public-key encryption, or otherwise, but you can never protect yourself that way against a determined attacker. A simple scheme that can't be bypassed without reverse-engineering will be sufficient; if someone can reverse-engineer, you're done for anyway.

A simplest scheme would be to hash to contents of the file with a private secret appended (or prepended), and append the hash to the end of the file. At the receiving end, you skip the hash, add the secret, re-hash, and compare.

If the checking tool should be stand-alone and simple to use, there are two options:

1. Build Qt to be linked statically, and linked statically to the C++ runtime. Then build the tool using that build of Qt: it will be quite small, well under 1MB, and will have no dependencies.
2. Offer the verifier as a single html file, and have it use the [JavaScript File API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). The user opens the html file in their web browser, drops the file onto a drop area, and gets an instant response. These days it will work on any common browser, i.e. Edge, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Konqueror, ...

An easy way of doing it in Qt would be to append the contents with a hex representation of a SHA-256 of the contents with a secret appended to them:

```
static const kHexSealSize = 2+64; // hex SHA-256
static QByteArray kSecret { "Things taste bad without salt." };

QByteArray sealHash(const QByteArray & data, int size = -1) {
  if (size < 0) size = data.size();
  QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
  hash.addData(data.constData(), size);
  hash.addData(kSecret);
  auto seal = QByteArray("\r\n") + hash.result().toHex();
  Q_ASSERT(hex.size() == kHexSealSize);
  return seal;
}

QByteArray seal(const QByteArray & data) {
  return data + sealHash(data);
}

/// Returns whether a seal is valid
bool checkSeal(const QByteArray & data) {
  if (data.size() < kHexSealSize) return false;
  auto hexSrc = data.right(kHexSealSize);
  auto hexCmp = sealHash(data, data.size() - kHexSealSize);
  return hexSrc == hexCmp;
}
```

Comment: I will probably use your approach, or do the following: Do as you suggested and then append the hash to the filename. The person checking the report can easily confirm that the record is valid. He does not need any tools for that. A simple sha256sum command would do it. Of cause this is not save as you already suggested and reverse engineering it would be pretty simple, but I think it is better than nothing and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent/detect modification, the standard way is perform message signing. Whether it is easy or not depends on what tool/library you use to perform such tasks.
For instant, openssl provide file signing function as both command line or library function.

Comment: wouldn't I than need to give a certificate for signing with each application?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you could use:

- **Use a checksum/hash** of the file, and compare it on the server. You can store the hash in a separate file, the file itself (you would have to modify the file to remove the hash), use it as some sort of customer support code or even name the file after the hash.
- **Encrypt** the file, users shouldn't be able to decrypt, modify and encrypt it again.
- **Launch a separate process** which stores the file in memory, deletes it, and then sends the file (if the user doesn't have a connection, wait until he has) - The user could kill the process, then the information is lost (if not, it is on disk, which he can access), encrypting it would block this attempt for example.
- **Change the extension** of the file (to `.dat` for example). This might not be the best way, but if the users don't know the file is a `csv` file, you might get away with it (security by obscurity is bad) :)

I personally would encrypt the file, as this is the most easiest way to implement it. It would also block every attempt to modify it, without much hassle (in constrast to the other ways).

Comment: Checksum/Hash -> What if the user opens the file, edits it, recalculates the hash and then saves it; Encryption -> need a secret key that is then stored in clear text in the application; Launch a separate process -> I want the file, the user should choose how to send the file to us; Maybe there is a even better solution out there

Comment: @user3482407 you could add a salt to the data for example

Comment: But how do I verify if the file is correct if I don't have the salt (since at the time the report is exported) or if the salt is added to the file, the user can add it's own salt to the file ;)

Comment: @user3482407 you should have the salt ;) And it isn't stored in the file itself, but can be anything not related to the data. You might use a hard coded string (that might not be a good idea, but you could still fetch it from the server instead), and use that as a salt.

Comment: hmm, I am still not satisfied with this approach. Furthermore if I hash the file and add the info of the hash to the file, the file has changed and to check if the file is correct, you would have remove the hash from the file before re-hashing it to be able to compare it. Using a separate file does not sound good to me either. This method also requires a connection to the server, which is complicated and customers without internet connection are completely lost.

Comment: @user3482407 Haha you're right ;) I hope my edit helps, and addresses your problems

Comment: @user3482407 "you would have remove the hash from the file before re-hashing it to be able to compare it" Not really :) You don't have to compute the hash over the entire file. You can compute it over the portion that excludes the originally appended hash.

Comment: That is right of cause, but you would need a custom application to do that. If you use linux for example you could use the "sha256sum" command to verify your file, which would be easy to use, portable and simple at the same time.